# Getting the WordPress Post ID of current post

Tags: php, wordpress

Anyone know how I can get the post ID of the current page?

So, if I'm on a particular post, inside my header.php, I want to be able to get the current post id.

Thanks!

Comment: Check the answer for this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22351038/get-the-current-page-id-inside-wordpress-plugin-page

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Try using this:

```
$id = get_the_ID();
```

Comment: Awesome, better that `get_the_ID()` which return error if shown in 404. Thank you :)

Answer (score 23):

You can use `$post->ID` to get the current ID.

Comment: Don't forget you'll have to globalize $post first, if you're using this method within a class. Also, this will only work once the $post is actually available, which would generally be after the 'init' action.

Comment: Throws warning after 3.0

Answer (score 21):

In most cases, [`get_the_ID()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_id/) will work fine:

```
$post_id = get_the_ID();
```

However, in some cases, you may need to use [`get_queried_object_id()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_queried_object_id/) instead:

```
$post_id = get_queried_object_id();
```

The reason for this is that the value returned by `get_the_ID()` is context-dependent and, in some cases, may return a different ID than the main post being queried. For further info, I recommend reading WordPress's documentation regarding [The Loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop).

Comment: this works, and I don't know why

Comment: @jaafarNasrallah - The reason it works is because the "ID" in "get_the_ID" is intentionally meant to be context-dependent, so its value can change depending on what part of "The Loop" you're in. By contrast, the ID in "get_queried_object_id" specifically refers to the ID being queried, which is what you're probably looking for if you're viewing this question.

Answer (score 18):

```
global $post;
echo $post->ID;
```

Comment: This answer would be better if it did more than just post a code solution. It's helpful to provide a short explanation of the code. (Also, I'm not a PHP expert, but it seems to me that after assigning a value to `$the_post_ID`, it would be appropriate to use that same variable name in the `echo` statement, instead of `$thePostID`).

Comment: Well it seems he's removed the error with the echo, but 'you Be Damned' if you think he's going to explain his code @PeterDuniho

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22351038/get-the-current-page-id-inside-wordpress-plugin-page/

Answer (score 9):

Try:

```
$post = $wp_query->post;
```

Then pass the function:

```
$post->ID
```

Answer (score 4):

You can get id through below Code...Its Simple and Fast

```
 <?php $post_id = get_the_ID();
   echo $post_id;
   ?>
```