# How to get access to post ID when using save_post action for WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

So I have this code that basically adds a post meta field when a mirror is created. The only issue i'm having is how I can access to the post id of the mirror that was just created? I've got the following code from this link: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post that has sample code, and adjusted it to my needs. The mirrors are created on the front end using a form. Using the code below, the post meta field values are not added to the mirrors when they are created. This is probably because `$post_id` doesn't hold anything.

From the link provided above, it says I have access to `$_GET` and `$_POST`, which one should I use and how do I get the ID of the post? Should I just use `$_POST->ID`?

```
// Order mirrors when they are created

function order_mirror_create($post_id) {

    $slug = 'mirror';

    if ( $slug != $_POST['post_type'] ) {
        return;
    }


    if ($videohost == "UploadAnime") {

        add_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'video_display_order', 1, true);

    } else {

        add_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'video_display_order', time(), true);

    }

}

add_action( 'save_post', 'order_mirror_create' );
```

EDIT: Updated my code using `$post->ID` and added `global $post`, however, this still does not work.

```
// Order mirrors when they are created

function order_mirror_create($post_id) {

    global $post;

    $slug = 'mirror';

    if ( $slug != $_POST['post_type'] ) {
        return;
    }


    if ($videohost == "UploadAnime") {

        add_post_meta($post->ID, 'video_display_order', 1, true);

    } else {

        add_post_meta($post->ID, 'video_display_order', time(), true);

    }

}

add_action( 'save_post', 'order_mirror_create' );
```

EDIT 2: Defined `$videohost` and used `$post_id`, however, still not working.

```
// Order mirrors when they are created

function order_mirror_create($post_id) {

    $slug = 'mirror';

    if ( $slug != $_POST['post_type'] ) {
        return;
    }

    $videohost = get_post_meta($post_id, 'video_provider', true);


    if ($videohost == "UploadAnime") {

        add_post_meta($post_id, 'video_display_order', 1, true);

    } else {

        add_post_meta($post_id, 'video_display_order', time(), true);

    }

}

add_action( 'save_post', 'order_mirror_create' );
```

Comment: this thread might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893435/getting-the-wordpress-post-id-of-current-post

Comment: Updated my code, using `$post->ID` and it still doesn't work.

Comment: have you tried `$id = get_the_ID();` ?

Comment: I've tried that before as well, could you possibly test it and see if it works for you as well?

Comment: `$videohost` has no value .( just FYI - thecondition will always be false )  but anyhow you will probably need to do `add_post_meta($post_id, 'video_display_order', 1, true);` and not `add_post_meta($post->ID, 'video_display_order', 1, true);`

Comment: I've updated my code as per your instructions as well as defined `$videohost` in my original post, however, this still does not work.