# get the current page id inside wordpress plugin page

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to get the current `page id` in WordPress plugin page outside the loop. And the code I wrote for getting current `page id` is in my plugin page. I tried many codes, but doesn't work

```
$page_object = get_queried_object();
$page_id     = get_queried_object_id();


 // "Dirty" pre 3.1
 global $wp_query;

$page_object = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
$page_id     = $wp_query->get_queried_object_id();
```

But it doesn't work for me .

```
  global $post;
  echo "pageid: ".$post->ID;
```

This is also not working.

When I try

```
     global $wp_query;
     $post_obj = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
     $Page_ID = $post_obj->ID;
     echo $Page_ID;
```

Then a error message appears

> Fatal error: Call to a member function get_queried_object()
>       on a non-object in
>       H:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\wpk\wpk.php 
>       on line 876

When I print:

```
global $wp_query;
print_r($wp_query);
```

then result is:

```
WP_Query Object
(
    [query] => 
    [query_vars] => Array
        (
        )

    [tax_query] => 
    [meta_query] => 
    [date_query] => 
    [queried_object] => 
    [queried_object_id] => 
    [request] => 
    [posts] => 
    [post_count] => 0
    [current_post] => -1
    [in_the_loop] => 
    [post] => 
    [comments] => 
    [comment_count] => 0
    [current_comment] => -1
    [comment] => 
    [found_posts] => 0
    [max_num_pages] => 0
    [max_num_comment_pages] => 0
    [is_single] => 
    [is_preview] => 
    [is_page] => 
    [is_archive] => 
    [is_date] => 
    [is_year] => 
    [is_month] => 
    [is_day] => 
    [is_time] => 
    [is_author] => 
    [is_category] => 
    [is_tag] => 
    [is_tax] => 
    [is_search] => 
    [is_feed] => 
    [is_comment_feed] => 
    [is_trackback] => 
    [is_home] => 
    [is_404] => 
    [is_comments_popup] => 
    [is_paged] => 
    [is_admin] => 
    [is_attachment] => 
    [is_singular] => 
    [is_robots] => 
    [is_posts_page] => 
    [is_post_type_archive] => 
    [query_vars_hash] => 
    [query_vars_changed] => 1
    [thumbnails_cached] => 
    [stopwords:WP_Query:private] => 
)
```

I don't know how to solve this, how to get the current `page id`.If you know how to solve this, then I need your support. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `get_queried_object_id()` should return the page id even outside the loop. Is the page you're running this on also the "Front Page" page in WordPress settings ?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`get_the_ID();` or  `$post->ID;` returns the current page or post id in Wordpress.

> But you need to ensure that your post is saved in wordpress post
> table, otherwise you **can't** get the id , simply because it is
> not an entry in wordpress database.

If it is a static page and it's not an entry in wordpress post then, `get_the_ID()` doesn't return anything.

**For example**:

`get_the_ID()` isn't going to work in `post archive pages`, `administration pages` in wordpress back-end etc.

**So *as per this question*** you are trying to get the id of the page that is a back-end plugin setting page or any archive page.

**UPDATE**

> ### Methods to get the current post id in wordpress

(1) `global $post;   $post->ID();`

(2) `global $wp_query; $post_id = $wp_query->get_queried_object_id();`

(3)  `global $wp_query;  $post_id = $wp_query->post->ID;`

(4)  `get_the_ID();`

- [  It is recommended that this tag must be within The Loop. ]

see this:

```php
function get_the_ID(){
  $post = get_post();
  return !empty($post) ? $post->ID : false;
}
```

**i.e. `get_the_ID()` returns the id of the current `$post`.**

(5) `get_query_var('page_id')`

- [ it is not going to work if we use pretty permalink ]
  https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_query_var/

Comment: For `Method (1)`, you will now want to use just `$post->ID` as the function `ID()` is no longer there.

Answer (score 15):

You can get `ID` of the post in current page outside the loop using the technique below:

```php
global $wp_query;
$post_id = $wp_query->post->ID;

$post = get_post( $post_id );
$slug = $post->post_name;
```

Comment: I am using this on function.php but is not working. Can you please guide?

Answer (score 5):

try to use below code to get the page id

```
get_the_ID();
```

Comment: This works not in every place, for example when needing the current page id in a Plugin.

Answer (score 4):

I guess that this is the proper solution:

```
$id = get_queried_object_id();
```

which equals to:

```
function get_queried_object_id() {
    global $wp_query;
    return $wp_query->get_queried_object_id();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Chosen answer is working *only if you put it in the Wordpress loop*. Outside it will render useless.

This is working everywhere:

```
global $wp_query;
$postID = $wp_query->post->ID;
```

Answer (score 1):

Above solutions did not works for me. I did it like this and works for me.

```
add_action ( 'after_setup_theme', 'custom_function' );
function custom_function() {
    $current_url = "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    // get page id from url and check for ssl enabled 
    $pageId = url_to_postid(set_url_scheme($current_url));
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You get see all of the settings and variables in `get_defined_vars()` function:

```
var_dump(get_defined_vars());
```

In your case you need to get '_GET' and inside 'post'... The code should look like this:

```
$tmp = get_defined_vars();
var_dump($tmp['_GET']['post']);
```

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who this still isn't working for, you will need to use some sort of add_action (you can choose which one you want to use). For my example, this will return the current page ID without any problems, regardless of whether in a plugin folder, functions php, or elsewhere.

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'showid');

function showid(){
    global $wp_query;
    $theid = intval($wp_query->queried_object->ID);
    echo $theid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing seemed to work for me until I tried this

```
<?php

function child_pages() {
  
    $page_id = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? (int) get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

    echo "<h2>" . $page_id . "</h2>";

}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'child_pages' );
?>
```