# How can I get id of current page outside loop and using plugin WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to get the id of wp current page and read those articles.

[get the current page id inside wordpress plugin page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22351038/get-the-current-page-id-inside-wordpress-plugin-page)

[WordPress Get the Page ID outside the loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127385/wordpress-get-the-page-id-outside-the-loop).

But all of these answers don't work for me. 
Does anybody know how to get the id of the current page in WP? 
If I use the following code

```
$wp_query->get_queried_object_id()
```

It gives me this error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function get_queried_object_id() on null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically the current page is always available via the globally scoped `$post` object. You *should* be able to get the ID of the current page via `$post->ID`, if you're in a function or method you will just need to define the variable as global by adding `global $post;` before trying to use it.

There are however exceptions to this, such as automatic pages, such as post type archives, and a large number of the administration pages.

As for your specific error: `Fatal error: Call to a member function get_queried_object_id() on null` It's saying the `$wp_query` variable is `null` you'll either need to add global scope to it via `global $wp_query;`, or you're trying to use it before it has been defined, in which case you'll need to defer your code via the actions API `add_action('some_event', 'your_function');`

**Update:**
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3127776/3332022 appears to be a rather concise answer

Comment: Hi, thanks, but this don't work for me. $post->ID return null.

Comment: If it's returning `null`, you either don't have global scope of the object, (Add `global $post;` immidently before your usage of it) or you're trying to access it before the "wp" action. The variable `$post` is only populated at this point, so you'd need to use a later action, you can see the available actions here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference

Comment: Post the code you are using. Have you added global $post;  above your code? Extra reading: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3127776/4034148

Comment: Sure I added before  $post->ID  this global $post;

Comment: this http://stackoverflow.com/a/3127776/3332022 don't work 
I have error  Fatal error: Call to a member function get_queried_object() on null  if I add 
global $wp_query;

$page_object = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
$page_id     = $wp_query->get_queried_object_id();

Comment: Can you post your full code so I can see where and how you're trying to do it?

Comment: Yes.
In main file of my plugin I added this  : 
1)
add_filter('init', 'get_obj_id');


function get_obj_id() {
 global $wp_query;
 $_SESSION['page_id'] = $wp_query->get_queried_object_id();
 return $wp_query->get_queried_object_id();
} 
don't work, null.
2) If I added this 
global $post;
$id = $post->ID; 
id also null\

Comment: So the "init" action runs to early, you'll need to run it at "wp" or later, see: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference for the explanation. but for now simply changing "init" to "wp" should get it working.

Comment: Yes, I changed to "wp" , now working. Beevee, thank you very much.