# Why the post view count function not working?

Tags: php, wordpress

Good day. I've been researching on how to track the post views count based on [this](http://bacsoftwareconsulting.com/blog/index.php/wordpress-cat/how-to-track-and-display-post-views-count-in-wordpress-without-a-plugin/) link

However, When I call the functions in the single.php which store in the loop, The post I just published still remain 0 view no matter how many times I refresh the browser ( The post isn't updating the post view count ). I'd be appreciated if there's any help.

My functions.php file- code for post views count

```
function subh_set_post_view($postID)
{
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = (int) get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if ($count == '') {
        $count = 0;
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
        return $count . 'View ';
    } else {
        $count++;
        update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, (string) $count);
    }
}

function getPostViews($postID){
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
        return "0 View";
    }
    return $count.' Views';
}

/**
 * Add a new column in the admin panel posts list
 *
 * @param $defaults
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
function subh_posts_column_views($defaults)
{
    $defaults['post_views'] = __('Views');

    return $defaults;
}

/**
 * Display the number of views for each posts on the admin panel
 *
 * @param $column_name
 * @param $id
 *
 * @return void simply echo out the number of views
 */
function subh_posts_custom_column_views($column_name, $id)
{
    if ($column_name === 'post_views') {
        echo subh_get_post_view(get_the_ID());
    }
}

add_filter('manage_posts_columns', 'subh_posts_column_views');
add_action('manage_posts_custom_column', 'subh_posts_custom_column_views', 5, 2);
```

My single.php file :

```
<?php 
    get_header();
?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" type="text/css" />
<div id="breadcrumbs" class="stuck_position">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="moduletable   col-sm-12">
                <div class="module_container">
                    <ul class="breadcrumb">
                        <li>
                            <a href="<?php echo esc_url(home_url()); ?>" class="pathway">
                                Home
                            </a>
                            <span class="divider">&nbsp;/&nbsp;</span>
                        </li>

                        <li class="active">
                            <span>
                                <?php the_title();?>
                            </span>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="content">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="content-inner">
                <!-- Left sidebar -->

                <div id="component" class="col-sm-12">
                    <main role="main">
                        <div id="system-message-container">
                        </div>

                        <article class="page-item">
                            <header class="item_header">
                                <h3 class="item_title">
                                    <span class="item_title_part_first">
                                        <?php the_title();?>
                                    </span>
                                </h3>
                            </header>
                            <div class="item_info">
                                <dl class="item_info_dl">
                                    <dd>
                                        <address class="item_createdby">
                                            <?php echo get_the_author(); ?> </address>
                                    </dd>
                                </dl>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </article>
                    </main>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<?php 
    if(function_exists('subh_set_post_view')) { 
    subh_set_post_view(get_the_ID()); 
    }
        echo getPostViews(get_the_ID());

?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>  
<?php get_footer();?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code.

```
function subh_set_post_view($postID)
{

    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = (int) get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);

    if ($count == 0) {      
        $count++;
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count++);
    } else {        
        $count++;
        update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
    }

}

function getPostViews($postID){
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);    
    return $count.' Views';
}

/**
 * Add a new column in the admin panel posts list
 *
 * @param $defaults
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
function subh_posts_column_views($defaults)
{
    $defaults['post_views'] = __('Views');

    return $defaults;
}

/**
 * Display the number of views for each posts on the admin panel
 *
 * @param $column_name
 * @param $id
 *
 * @return void simply echo out the number of views
 */
function subh_posts_custom_column_views($column_name, $id)
{
    if ($column_name === 'post_views') {
        echo getPostViews(get_the_ID());
    }
}

add_filter('manage_posts_columns', 'subh_posts_column_views');
add_action('manage_posts_custom_column', 'subh_posts_custom_column_views', 5, 2);
```

[image]

Comment: glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

> `get_the_ID()` : Retrieve the ID of the current item in the WordPress
>   Loop.

That's why your function doesn't work. You can use  `get_the_ID()` only inside the loop, you can't use it on single.php

Read all answers and comments of [Getting the WordPress Post ID of current post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893435/getting-the-wordpress-post-id-of-current-post)

Comment: but based on the website, the author provided a real example in which you can call the loop in single.php :/ so why not ? I don't think this is a problem, I just checked the posts which I set the views count manually to >100 and the functions work, the view count is updating. It just don't work with the latest published news and that's the issue I'm undergoing