# WordPress getting custom meta value outside of loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to get the value of the custom field `'product_url'` this code is going in functions.php and I'm using the shortcode in a single post. The custom field `'product_url'` exists on this post and is not empty.

```
 function metavalue() {
                    GLOBAL $post;
                    $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'product_url', true);
                    echo $meta;


                    }
 add_shortcode('url_short', 'metavalue');
```

nothing is being displayed when I use the shortcode. `var_dump($meta);` will output

> string(0) ""

.

Comment: have you debug the code that @meta is not empty within function ?

Comment: Dont use `echo` use return, sometimes the shortcode will print in weird places as it executes before the post content is completed and output.  Or call exit following the output, that way it's much easier to find it in the page.  I am not sure if it is just a display issue or not, but the code looks fine to me.

Comment: I've tried using return $meta; its still not outputting anything.

Comment: @Jesses I have updated my code as well as.  please debug issue. make sure there is value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass $postid to your get_post_meta function.

```
 function metavalue() {
    global $post;
    $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'product_url', true);
    return $meta;
  }
 add_shortcode('url_short', 'metavalue');
```

**How to debug :**

- Check product or post have product_url value.
- get the ID of product / Post you can get via admin edit post /page.
- Pass ID as static value in short code function.

  `function metavalue() {
    global $post;
    $meta = get_post_meta(112, 'product_url', true); // 112 static postid
    return $meta;
    }
   add_shortcode('url_short', 'metavalue');`

**Version 2 : Shortcode with parameter**

Combine user attributes with known attributes and fill in defaults when needed.

The pairs should be considered to be all of the attributes which are supported by the caller and given as a list. The returned attributes will only contain the attributes in the $pairs list.

If the $atts list has unsupported attributes, then they will be ignored and removed from the final returned list.

```
function metavalue($atts) {

 $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'postid' => 1,            
        ), $atts, 'url_short' );
  global $post;

  $meta = get_post_meta($atts['postid'], 'product_url', true); // 112 static postid
  return $meta;
  }
 add_shortcode('url_short', 'metavalue');
```

**How to use:**

```
[url_short postid=1911]
```

Comment: The `global $post` should contain the ID of the current post.  For example see this answer  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893435/getting-the-wordpress-post-id-of-current-post  That said it wouldn't be a bad option to add, `if(empty($atts['post_id']))` etc.

Comment: if you need custom id

Comment: ` function metavalue() {
                        global $post;
                        $meta = get_post_meta(1911, 'product_url', true);
                        echo $post->ID;
                        return $meta;
                    }
                    add_shortcode('url_short', 'metavalue');` works as intended. when i use echo $post->ID; it will output 215, however in the admin the post ID is 1911.

Comment: This means you are not viewing a post 1911.

Comment: You might be getting `page`s post id.

Comment: That code works great, thank you. Is there a way to get the correct post ID dynamically so each shortcode doesn't have to include the post ID?

Comment: Dynamic post id mean current page  or post id. Which is not possible until you reach that page or post. here if you viewing archive or category page then you can't it. if you are on detail or single page then ID will be correct.

Comment: I hope this answer is helpful to you. if it is just mark accepted so this will helpful to other person as well.